# What is the condition to have a Lipschitz continuous the gradient for convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

According to Prof. Vandenberg's lecture notes [ECE236C (Spring 2019) - Gradient Method](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) a function is called Lipschitz continuous gradient when

$$
\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2 \leq \alpha\|y-x\|_2
$$

Note that the definition does not assume that $f$ is a convex function.

However, if $f$ is a convex function we have
$$
f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x),y-x \rangle + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2
$$

Can we prove the reverse, i.e., if we have

$$
f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x),y-x \rangle + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2
$$
then 
$$
\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2 \leq \alpha\|y-x\|_2
$$

Hint: using $
f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x),y-x \rangle + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2
$ we can conclude that $g(x)=\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x\|_2^2-f(x)$ is convex. Since $g(x)$ is convex, monotonicity of the gradient of $g$ results in

$$
\langle \nabla f(x) - f(y),y-x \rangle \leq \alpha\|y-x\|_2^2
$$
but how is possible to get back to the following?
$$
\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2 \leq \alpha\|y-x\|_2
$$
I am wondering if the above method is right way to prove it. In addition, is there any other condition that can be applied to the convex function $f(x)$ to have Lipschitz continuous gradient?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider the indicator function for the non-negative real numbers.  Then I(x) = 0 if x is >= 0, and $\infty$ otherwise.  (Here, I is defined on the augmented real numbers.)

I is convex, but I is not Lipscitz since the derivative at 0 is unbounded.

Comment: $|x|$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Kadeng  Thanks.  I have no idea what I was thinking.  I hope I have fixed it now.